# Make POST request from php file to another php file

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to send a post request that does the excact same thing as the code below, but from a php file to another php file. In other words I want to make the post request with PHP and not Javascript. I have tried different methods but they all get the content from the php file, and not make the post like ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./delete.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: data => console.log(data),
    error: err => console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: can you provide the php code that you've tried?

Comment: If you use `curl()` it should make the POST request. You would get the content if you use `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560512/send-http-request-with-curl-to-local-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code sample I used. Thanks to @Amirhossein Shahbazi for the suggestion.
Link to the question: [send http request with CURL to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560512/send-http-request-with-curl-to-local-file)

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost:8000/fe.php';
// The submitted form data, encoded as query-string-style
// name-value pairs
$body = 'monkey=uncle&rhino=aunt';
$c = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c);
?>
```